# How to get variable names from Thymeleaf template

Tags: java, thymeleaf, template-engine

I'm doing research to find suitable template engine for a new project. One of the features the template engine must have is dynamically get all defined variables from template file.

I'm trying to figure out, if it is supported feature of Thymeleaf template library to parse template and get list of all defined variables.

Variable list can be asked from IContext. For example:

```
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver tr = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
tr.setPrefix("thymeleaf/");
tr.setSuffix(".html");

TemplateEngine te = new TemplateEngine();
te.setTemplateResolver(tr);

Context ctx = new Context();
te.process("example-template", ctx);

ctx.getVariableNames();
```

But of course it's empty since it lists only input variables (in this case input variables were not given at all).

I looked around in API, but didn't find anything. That lead me to think, maybe it's not supported feature at all, like in Freemarker. But since Thymeleaf is big project, I fear that I just don't where to look. Please help.

I'm using the latest Thymeleaf version 3.0.2.